# Is the default serialized form appropriate in this case

Tags: java, serialization

In Effective Java second edition, as a bad example of the use of the default serialized form is given this class:

```
// Awful candidate for default serialized form
public final class StringList implements Serializable {
    private int size = 0;
    private Entry head = null;
    private static class Entry implements Serializable {
        String data;
        Entry next;
        Entry previous;
    }
    ... // Remainder omitted
}
```

The reason given is "the default serialized form will painstakingly mirror every entry in the linked list
and all the links between the entries, in both directions." And it then goes on to say that we should just serialize this class as an array of strings.

In Java EE 6 tutorial is another example - [the order application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqst.html). In it, there's a class `Part` that also uses the default serialized form and looks like this:

```
public class Part implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3082087016342644227L;
    private Date revisionDate;
    private List<Part> parts;
    private Part bomPart;
    private Serializable drawing;
    private String description;
    private String partNumber;
    private String specification;
    private VendorPart vendorPart;
    private int revision;
    ...
}
```

Since a `Part` contains a `List` of `Part`s, don't we have the same problem? The default serialized form will recursively serialize every `Part` object, contained within another `Part` object.

Comment: Only if you create a circle, where part `A` contains a list containing part `B` and `B` contains a list containing `A`.

Comment: The point with a `LinkedList` is that it's very cheap to create a `LinkedList` from an array. And Java serialization is heavily optimised for arrays. In your second example **information is lost**. There is no way to recover the relationships if you don't save them.

Comment: @Smutje this is nonsense. The Java serialization API will happily serialize circular references. It would be completely useless if it didn't.

Comment: **If** it is a problem, **then** use [`Externalizable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html). Wait until it is a problem, [*premature optimization is the root of all evil*](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) - Knuth.